# Getting contents of a listbox or a list from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I have tried to find a method for this but I can't seem to get anything to work. I have a form that has a button that opens up a second form with a listbox on it that is filled with items on that screen. I then place all of those items into a list. These items, once they are on form1, will be placed into a listbox again.

The problem I am having is that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access either the elements of the listbox or the list and I need access to it from the main form or else I can't do anything else.

```
public partial class product_list : Form
{
    public List<string> ProductList { get; private set; }

    public product_list()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ProductList = new List<string>();
    }

    public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string selectedItem = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        listBox2.Items.Add(selectedItem);
        ProductList.Add(selectedItem);
    }

    public void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = (string)listBox2.SelectedItem; 
        listBox2.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
        ProductList.Remove(selectedItem);
    }

    public void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();   
    }
}
```

This is my second form. And this below here is my main form code so far

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form productSelect = new product_list();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Register.Visible = true;
    } 

    private void btnService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        productSelect.ShowDialog();

        var itemsFromSecondForm = productSelect.ProductList;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm not very far into it but this has been holding me up for a while.

Anyone have a method that I can use to get either all of the elements from the listbox or the list itself in form1?

EDIT: Updated my code to what I have now. Still receiving an error

Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'ProductList' and no extension method 'ProductList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: have you stepped thru the code...? also what is the List is it Private, Public, Static..? I think by default if you do not explicitly declare the type of list as `public` then it's private by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `ProductList` a public property, with a private setter. Initialize it in your constructor. *(I gave it a private setter because you have no need to instantiate it from outside of the second Form.)*

```
public List<string> ProductList { get; private set; }

public product_list()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ProductList = new List<string>();
}
```

Then you can access it in the main Form, after you close the second Form:

```
private void btnProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productSelect.ShowDialog();

    var itemsFromSecondForm = productSelect.ProductList;
}
```

---

Regarding the error in your latest update:

> Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'ProductList' and no extension method 'ProductList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is because that public property is in your `product_list` class, not in the base `Form` class. You have to create an instance of your class, not an instance of `Form`.

Also, FWIW, I prefer to create instances of Forms as close as possible to where I'm using them:

```
private void btnProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // A "using" block will take care of disposing of your Form
    //  when you're finished using it.
    using (var productSelect = new product_list())
    {
        productSelect.ShowDialog();

        var itemsFromSecondForm = productSelect.ProductList;

        // do something with itemsFromSecondForm
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to get an error on form1 on 

var itemsFromSecondForm = productSelect.ProductList;

Any idea what would cause the error to say that the form "does not contain a definition for 'productlist'

Comment: No that's not the issue that's just how I typed it here by accident

Answer (score 0):

To answer your Error 1:

Change this:

```
Form productSelect = new product_list();
```

to this:

```
product_list productSelect = new product_list();
```